# vb6 Extracts to MS Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, vb6, ms-office

So my company is transition from 2007 to 2013 - and we have some reports writting in VB6 applications where do extract data from database and write it to excel. It seems that there is some changes that were made and they're this a very difficult process...

This is how I create the declarations for some of my extracts...This code is in my VB6 application!

```
dim xlsheet1 as Excel.Worksheet ' i have OPTION EXPLICIT and do this at the top
```

In my function to actually write this report I do this....

```
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet1 = xlBook.Worksheets.Add
```

This worked in Office 2007 - but now it seems to hang up on Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add

Any idea?

Comment: In your VB6 project do you have any references set?

Comment: Did you move from 32bit 2007 to 64bit 2013 by chance?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/219151

Comment: @TimWilliams - yes I do - I have Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library - which I think directly relates to this. There are also about a dozen more (MS outlook, MS excel, OLE automation, ActiveX data objects, etc)

Comment: @Comintern nope x64 Win 7 to x64 Win 10

Comment: I was referring to the Office install bit-ness.

Comment: @Comintern - 32 to 32 sorry

Comment: (a) When you say "it seems to hang up on", do you actually means it hangs (i.e. application becomes completely unresponsive) or does it generate an error message of some sort?  (b) Do you get the same symptoms if an existing instance of Excel is open prior to running your code as you get when Excel is not already running when you start your code?

Comment: It doesn't freeze - ust keeps loading with no end result - i get a msg box with two button(generic one) SWITCH TO and RETRY. I make sure the process is closed in Task Manager (but I ran it with it open, same issue). One time I received a different message saying something about a Add-on issue - vs11adapterexcel but i have not seen it again

Comment: I would take a look at the add-ins in Excel, then,

Comment: @JimHewitt I looked at them but cannot find anything like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue when we migrated from Windows XP to Windows 7. The application was not able to create the excel files. 
I changed the declaration from "ExcelSheet" to Object

```
Dim xlApp as Object
Dim xlBook as Object
```

Then at the time of using it I set it to excel objects

```
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
Set xlBook = New Excel.Workbooks.Add
```

Hope this will work for you !!!